# Is possible provide username from DocuSign account for sign tab?

Tags: docusignapi

We have only email for our recipients and do not have them fullname. 
We need provide in SignHere tab them fullname that they set in DocuSign. 
1. Can I do it with SOAP API? 
2. Can I invoke fullname recipients before send?

Comment: Hi Korvinko, can you please clarify your question as I'm not sure what exactly you're asking?  If you simply add a `fullName` tab to your document then yes, it will pull in the recipient's full name automatically when it's their turn to sign, but I'm not sure if that's what you are asking.   https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Tabs/Full Name Tab.htm

Comment: We do not have information about recipient. We do not have his full name. Only email. So  can we use only email address to get full name recipient? Or can we omit full name when providing recipient information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolve problem by request full name from user in our UI.